# IOstream on MacOSX

Tags: c++, macos

I just got a Macbook, and I just installed gpp to make some programs in C++, but when I am including iostream, i am getting this error :

`main.cpp:2: error: Requested include file not found`

Here is my code :

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "test" << std::endl;
}
```

Thanks if you can help me !

Comment: How did you go about installing your compiler? In particular, do you have the Xcode command line tools also installed? Also, what command are you using to build the file that produces that error when you run it?

Comment: I did a simple `brew install gpp`, and I don't have install Xcode yet.
Basically, the gpp command, like gpp `gpp main.cpp`

Comment: `gpp` is just the preprocessor. It doesn't compile, and it doesn't bring the standard library along with it when you install it; it just substitutes in included files if it can find them. You are probably looking for the `g++` command from the `gcc` Homebrew package instead.

Answer (score 0):

I used xcode-select --install on the terminal and everything started working.

Best of luck